# Overhead of no-op Forth words

Tags: forth

When writing compliant standard Forth, words like `CHARS` need to be used a lot, which have no actual effect in my Forth environment. Will no-ops like this add overhead to the Forth dictionary, or my colon definitions?

Answer (score 3):

No-op words for standards compliance or to annotate code have no significant overhead in colon definitions when they are defined as `IMMEDIATE`. This is because `IMMEDIATE` causes the word to execute, rather than be compiled, while compiling a word. Therefore, nothing is added to the compiled code at all.

As an example:

```
\ Potential implementation of CHARS for a Forth environment
: CHARS ; IMMEDIATE

: test CHARS ;

SEE test  \ prints : test ;
```

This is how, for example, gforth [implements](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gforth.git/tree/kernel/basics.fs#n48) `CHARS`.

However, not all Forths will use this optimisation. If not, then a redundant call to the function will be compiled into the code. If this is a problem for you, Forth allows you to redefine `CHARS` etc. with the above colon definition to apply the optimisation anyway.